# Retrieving and XDocuments attribute value via linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

'm having a problem figuring out the correct select statement here

I have the following XML

```
<configuration>
  <other sections>
  <runtime>
    <Binding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing Path="some path string" />
    </Binding>
    <Concurrent enabled="false" />
  </runtime>
  <other sections>
</configuration>
```

Im trying to do a select where I retrieve the Path string value

So far I have this

```cs
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(XmlfilePath);

var query = (from c in xdoc.Descendants("probing")
where c.Attribute("Path") != null
select c.Attribute("Path").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

But this doesn't work, query is null

Answer (score 3):

Because the name of your attribute is  `Path` not `privatePath`.Also you can use explicit cast and then you don't need the null-check:

```
var query = (from c in xdoc.Descendants("probing")
             select (string)c.Attribute("Path")).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Update:** it seems your element has a namespace so you need to specify the namespace like this:

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1";

var query = (from c in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "probing")
             select (string)c.Attribute("Path")).FirstOrDefault();
```

You may want to take a look at the documentation for more details about xml namespaces: [Working with XML Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387093.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, for the example I made "privatePath" in the xml just Path, forgot to change the code sample. 

I tried your example just now, but its still null the query value

Comment: @Domitius now I see the namespace sorry.I updated my answer try it again.